# Display dropdown field (ModelChoiceField) populated by a database on the HTML page

Tags: python, html, django, forms, django-forms

I'm brand new to web design and HTML, and I need a ModelChoiceField populated with unique values (specifically the 'CATEGORY' field) from a database of parts. After some digging around, I believe I have figured out how to do that (though I may be wrong), but now I need to know how to display it on my index.html. Here's what I have:

Forms.py:

```
   class dropdown(forms.Form):
    cats = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Part.objects.distinct('CATEGORY'))
    class Meta:
        model = Part
```

Views.py:

```
#attempt at a dropdown form
def show_part(request):
    form = dropdown()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = dropdown(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            #redirect to the url where you'll process the input
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/templates/index.html') # insert reverse or url
    errors = form.errors or None # form not submitted or it has errors
    return render(request, '/collection/templates/index.html',{
        'form': form,
        'queryset': queryset,
        'errors': errors,
   })
```

index.html (my template)

```
<form action="cat-select1/" method="POST"> 
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="cat_select1"> Part Category: </label>
    {{ form.cats }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Why isnt my dropdown showing up on the page? Thanks in advance.

Comment: please show the concerned .html file

Comment: The only HTML that's written is unrelated to this form. I just want the form to show up on my homepage underneath the title.

Comment: Then you need a template that includes it. Please show that.

Comment: Well I mean that's what I was asking about. But I've done some research and I've added what I have now to the post body.